Engine Failure - Immediately After Takeoff
Cessna 172 scenario: engine quits within seconds of takeoff at 200 ft AGL, necessitating a straight ahead crash landing. Assuming flaps 0, what is the optimal air speed to pitch for? Does it make any sense to use flaps?

Are you a student? What does your instructor say?

We try not to call it a "crash" landing, the aim here is just a normal landing without power!
As with all questions like this check your specific aircraft's POH, as that has the details for your model of C172.
Having got that obligatory line out the way, the best glide speed on my kneeboard for the 172 I fly in is 65 KIAS in the clean configuration. I know this because I brief it, along withwhat I'll do on an EFATO, every time I do my captains brief - and that includes to myself if I'm the only person on board! It's a good habit to get into, hopefully ensuring that if it does ever happen I'll just act instinctively.
Looking at a C172 POH Online it states exactly the steps you should take on page 3-5.

ENGINE FAILURE IMMEDIATELY AFTER TAKE OFF

Airspeed -- 65 KIAS (Flaps UP)
60 KIAS (Flaps DOWN)
Mixture -- IDLE CUT OFF
Fuel Selector Value -- OFF
Ignition Switch -- OFF
Wing Flaps -- AS REQUIRED
Master Switch -- OFF


So that answers your second question of whether it makes sense to use flaps - the answer is "if required".
From 200' you're going to be back on the ground in less than 30 seconds, and at a distance of something like 600 meters assuming zero wind. With a headwind that distance will be shorter. The most important thing you can do is, as always, aviate. Keep flying the aeroplane and do what is necessary to save your life.

Item (1) can be interpreted in different ways: (a) pitch for specific air speed depending on current flaps configuration, or (b) adjust the flaps as/if your air speed decreases to 60 KIAS. These are not mutually exclusive. What is the right way to interpret item (1)?
Second, how do I make sens of AS REQUIRED in item (5)?

@user443854 IMO, 1) is saying "if you are taking off clean, your best speed is 65, however if you're taking off with flaps it is 60". As for 5) if you need the extra drag to land back safely use flaps, otherwise don't - as per any landing really! In any case, it's all rather academic, as per my final paragraph, you have seconds, if not less, to think about this - just aviate. Worry about the debrief for what you should have done for the clubhouse/pub/pearly gates as appropriate. The key here is practice with an instructor and make it a memory action. You don't have time to think!

I’ve only flown 172s a couple of times and have never had an engine failure, so I’ll make a few observations from basic principles.  If you’re a wise pilot and are lucky enough to have enough runway left to stop then your first priority will be to get the nose down and maintain airspeed.  Then you can flare in to minimise sink rate as you touchdown.  If you have little space then you might keep your airspeed closer to stall, landing more heavily but with lower groundspeed.  If you’ve no clear ground to land on then it will be a snap decision as to what you want to hit and at what angle.  If you’ve just taken off it’s unlikely that you’ll have your flaps fully retracted.  I’m sure that others will have plenty more to contribute.

The optimal airspeed to pitch for, Vbg, around 65 knots flaps up, is the greatest glide distance.  200 feet/1 to 9 glide ratio is around 1/3 mile. (without headwind).
So, you're not going too far, even at Vbg.  It might be best to immediately prepare to land, as slow as possible.
If a suitable landing site is closer, use the short field landing procedure, go flaps 30, and approach at 55 knots.
Flaps lower the stall speed to 40 knots.  48 knots has 44 % more impact energy.
The only reason not to lower flaps is if a suitable landing area is available with a longer roll out, or if it is windy. The simplest way would be to pitch down to 65 knots for a zero flaps landing.
